# Matrix column comparison

Tags: c++, algorithm, matrix

I have to compare matrix columns.

I tried many variations, but as far as I got, is when I compare "next to each other" columns.

```
// N rows
// M columns

#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    ios_base::sync_with_stdio(false);

    int N, M, ok = 1;
    const int maxn = 1000;
    const int maxm = 1000;
    short H[maxn][maxm];

    cin >> N >> M;

    for (int i=0; i<N; i++){
        for (int j=0; j<M; j++){
            cin >> H[i][j];
        }
    }

    for (int j = 1; j < M; ++j)
    {
        ok = 1;
        for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i)
        {
            if (H[i][j-1] >= H[i][j])
            {
                ok = 0;
            }
        }
        if (ok)
        {
            cout << j+1 << endl;
            return 0;
        }
    }
    cout << -1 << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

I have to give back the index of the first column where is true, that the column's every element is greater than ANY OTHER column's elements. (Not summarized.)

For example:

```
10 10 12 15 10
11 11 11 13 20
12 16 16 16 20
```

It returns with `4`, because the 4th column's every element is greater, than the 1st column's elements.
If there are none, it has to return with `-1`.

Comment: Why doesn't it return `1` since the column of index `1` has bigger elements than the column of index `0` ?

Comment: Equaility is not allowed. Strictly "greater than".

Comment: Ok, i get it. And what is your problem ? Does your code run ? find the answer ?

Comment: It runs, but i get 35 / 100 when i test it. I have to compare every column with every column. So not just ```j``` with ```j+1``` , which is M-1 , but ```j``` with all the other columns which is N*M.

Comment: Does it have to compare with previous columns only or also with the columns after?

Comment: Previous columns and columns after.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need another inner loop to go through every other column:

```cpp
#include <ios>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    using namespace std;
    ios_base::sync_with_stdio(false);

    int N, M, ok = 1;
    const int maxn = 1000;
    const int maxm = 1000;
    short H[maxn][maxm];

    cin >> N >> M;

    for (int i=0; i<N; i++){
        for (int j=0; j<M; j++){
            cin >> H[i][j];
        }
    }

    for (int j = 0; j < M; ++j)
    {
        for (int j2 = 0; j2 < M; ++j2)
        {
            if (j == j2) continue;
            ok = 1;
            for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i)
            {
                if (H[i][j] <= H[i][j2])
                {
                    ok = 0;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (ok)
            {
                cout << j + 1 << endl;
                return 0;
            }
        }
    }
    cout << -1 << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Given the input:

```
3 5
10 10 10 15 10
11 11 11 13 20
12 16 16 14 20
```

This prints:

```
4
```

[See it on Rextester](https://rextester.com/ZAUGV20515)

Comment: I understand now. I thought of another inner loop, but I didn't know how to use it. Thank you!